# how to deal with categorical variables in spark-1.6?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am doing a Random Forest classification model on my data set.
There are some categorical variables that I deal with them by using oneHotEncode method which provided by spark1.6. Finally, I got many sparse vectors

My codes :

```
     def oneHotEncode(a: String,b:String,c:String,selectedData:DataFrame) : 

      DataFrame = {
      val indexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol(a).setOutputCol(b).fit(selectedData)
      val indexed = indexer.transform(selectedData)
      val encoder = new OneHotEncoder().setInputCol(b).setOutputCol(c)
      val encoded = encoder.transform(indexed)
      return encoded
}
var data1 = oneHotEncode("ispromoteroom","ispromoteroomIndex","ispromoteroomVec",selectedData)
```

The question is how can I transform those sparse vectors and other original continuous variables in data set into LabeledPoint data type?

Answer (score 0):

I have followed this [tutorial](https://www.codementor.io/spark/tutorial/spark-python-mllib-decision-trees), it's very helpful.

```
def create_labeled_point(line_split):
    # leave_out = [41]
    clean_line_split = line_split[0:41]

    # convert protocol to numeric categorical variable
    try: 
        clean_line_split[1] = protocols.index(clean_line_split[1])
    except:
        clean_line_split[1] = len(protocols)

    # convert service to numeric categorical variable
    try:
        clean_line_split[2] = services.index(clean_line_split[2])
    except:
        clean_line_split[2] = len(services)

    # convert flag to numeric categorical variable
    try:
        clean_line_split[3] = flags.index(clean_line_split[3])
    except:
        clean_line_split[3] = len(flags)

    # convert label to binary label
    attack = 1.0
    if line_split[41]=='normal.':
        attack = 0.0

    return LabeledPoint(attack, array([float(x) for x in clean_line_split]))

training_data = csv_data.map(create_labeled_point)
test_data = test_csv_data.map(create_labeled_point)
```